# Cloud Run Request Limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

Currently, Cloud Run has a request limit of **32 Mb** per request, which makes it impossible to upload files like videos (which placed with no changes to GCP Storage). Meantime **All Quotas** page doesn't list this limitation as the one you can request an increase from support. So question is - does anyone know how to increase this limit or how to make it possible (uploading video and bigger files) to Cloud Run with given limitation?

Comment: The 32 MB limit is fixed. This is due to a Load Balancer/Proxy (GFE) sitting in front of Cloud Run. You could change your design to upload "chunks" of data in multiple requests.

Comment: The 32 MB limit is documented here under `Maximum request size`: https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas

Comment: Has anyone implemented the approach with multiple requests (chunks)? Does it work?

Comment: I have, it works great. Upload chunks to a bucket using dotted suffix so the chunks can be sorted. After final chunk is uploaded, sort and do a compose operation to combine: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composing-objects#create-composite-cli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google recommended best practice is to use Signed URLs to upload files, which is likely to be more scalable and reliable (over flaky networks) for file uploads:

see this url for further information:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Seems it is a solution. Thank you a lot. Probably another way to go round is to to use File API in the browser.

Comment: Your answer is the recommended method. However, Presigned URLs are not more reliable over flaky networks than any other HTTP request method. Their success depends on the techniques, error detection and retry logic in the software/libraries that are used. The recommendation for Presigned URLS is a security recommendation and not for performance nor reliability.

Comment: I was referring to resumable uploads feature by comment about flaky network. Presigned URL should also help with scalability as your app does not have to deal with it. Client needs to architect it using retry logic. It can make a big difference in end user experience especially for large file uploads .

Comment: The question was how to increase the limit or go about limitations as Cloud Run is the only option to run the application for us right now. Therefore the answer is valid and helps to go around for upload of big files.

Answer (score 4):

Update since the other answers were posted - the request size can be unlimited if using HTTP/2.

See https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits which says "Request    Maximum HTTP/1 request size, in MB  32 if using HTTP/1 server. No limit if using HTTP/2 server."

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, don't forget to enable http/2 by setting

server.http2.enabled = true

in application.properties. Otherwise you will get the error message:
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination

Answer (score 3):

As per official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits), the **maximum request size** limit for Cloud Run (which is 32 MB) cannot be increased.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same issue in cloudrun, and my request was limited to 32MB. I tried signed URLs, but in my case, since I had a form where I attach the file, I always needed to read it, and it got blocked by that limitation. Finally, the solution was to switch the site to HTTP/2, and I solved the problem.

**Note: Not only do you have to deploy to cloudrun changing to HTTP/2 in the networking tab, but you also have to serve the website with a server that supports HTTP/2. For example, hypercorn.
In my Dockerfile, I simply ran it on ASGI:

CMD exec hypercorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 myproject.asgi:application**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).